# Webpack 1.15 disable sourceMappingUrl

Tags: javascript, reactjs, npm, webpack

I am using webpack 1.15. The sourceMappingUrl is generated. I tried many things to avoid this, but no success.

```
debug:false,
devtools: false,
```

Also tried:

```
devtools: 'hidden-source-map',
```

I also tried removing devtools completely. Didn't work. The reason I want to do this is, I want to append something to source map url using the below code. But this results in 2 source mapping URL's in my generated file.

```
devtool: 'hidden-source-map', // SourceMap without reference in original file

  new webpack.SourceMapDevToolPlugin({
    filename: '[file].map',
    append: `\n//# sourceMappingURL=${path}[url]`
  })
```